# В чем суть ошибки в построении предложения с однородными членами?

Tags: грамотная-речь, однородные-члены

Объясните, пожалуйста, поподробнее, почему такой порядок слов недопустим:

> Богатство русского словаря позволяет **точно назвать не только** тот
>   или иной предмет, его признаки, различные действия, но и выразить
>   самые разнообразные оттенки значения.

И требуется только так:

> Богатство русского словаря позволяет **не только точно назвать** тот или
>   иной предмет, его признаки, различные действия, но и выразить самые
>   разнообразные оттенки значения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Богатство русского словаря позволяет точно назвать не только тот или
>   иной предмет, его признаки, различные действия, но и выразить самые
>   разнообразные оттенки значения.

Здесь действительно ошибка, причем грамматическая. Посмотрите на структуру. 
Составной союз *"не только ..., но и ..."* требует для заполнения обозначенных отточиями членов каких-то однородных членов: *"В футбол играют не только **мальчики**, но и **девочки**"*, *"Я умею не только **петь**, но и **аккомпанировать на гитаре**"*, *"Богатство русского словаря позволяет не только **точно назвать** тот или иной предмет, его признаки, различные действия, но и **выразить** самые разнообразные оттенки значения".*
То есть "играют мальчики и девочки", "умею петь и аккомпанировать", "позволяет назвать и выразить".

В исходном же варианте получается нелепица: позволяет точно назвать *признаки* и *выразить*. С перестановкой однородных: "назвать выразить и признаки".

Comment: Абсолютно правильный ответ!) Поддерживаю.

Answer (score 2):

В "правильном" варианте противопоставлены выражения "точно назвать" и "выразить". "Мы можем не только точно назвать, но ещё и сделать что-то ещё". В "неправильном" варианте вся фраза построена на том, что нечто можно ожидаемо точно назвать, а что-то при этом тоже можно точно назвать, но это должно быть неожиданным для читателя: "можно точно назвать не только это, но вот ещё и вот это". Однако содержание предложения противоречит этой структуре. Вместо того, чтобы продолжать линию того, что можно назвать точно, а что, например, нельзя, автор вставляет "выразить". Выразить и назвать несколько отличаются по смыслу, хотя и довольно близки. Я бы не стал называть это прямо ошибкой. И даже оставить так можно было бы. Но "правильный" вариант звучит не так криво, а его смысл более прозрачен.

Почему возникает такое противоречие? Из-за смещения "не только". В первом случае оно обобщает всю фразу, во втором встраивается в её фрагмент, который условно можно маркировать как "точно назвать...".

Answer (score 1):

*Суть* грамматической ошибки в том, что в схеме "**назвать не только А, но и В**" А и В должны быть прямыми дополнениями при переходном глаголе "*назвать*". В нашем случае в качестве А выступает оборот на основе **существительного** "предмет" *в винительном падеже* (что нормально), а в качестве В  фигурирует фигурирует глагольный **инфинитив**. Получилось что-то вроде "*назвать не только (А) **предмет**, но и (В) **выразить***". Не имеет значения, как далее конкретизирован инфинитив "выразить", поскольку "**назвать выразить**" - то же, что "сапоги всмятку".